# Python - round up to the nearest ten

Tags: python, rounding

If I get the number 46 and I want to round up to the nearest ten. How do can I do this in python?

46 goes to 50.

Comment: Nearest *ten* (`10`) or nearest *tenth* (`0.1`)? What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: what do you want to get for `-46`: `-50` or `-40`?

Comment: What type of numbers?  `int`s?  `float`s?  `Decimal` instances?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can use [`math.ceil()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/math.html#math.ceil) to round up, and then multiply by 10

Python 2

```
import math

def roundup(x):
    return int(math.ceil(x / 10.0)) * 10
```

Python 3 (the only difference is you no longer need to cast the result as an `int`)

```
import math

def roundup(x):
    return math.ceil(x / 10.0) * 10
```

To use just do

```
>>roundup(45)
50
```

Comment: That does not work always: If `x = 1000000000000000010` then `print(int(math.ceil(x / 10.0)) * 10)` outputs `1000000000000000000`.

Comment: I think that's because you're going past the python int limit

Comment: As far as I know, there is no longer a limit on the maximum size of an integer in Python, see here: https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/71008/comparing-python-and-c-part-1-integer-variables

Comment: It is more likely because you hit the `eps` and finite precision take over after that.

Comment: The expression `math.ceil(x / 10) * 10` works just fine. No need for those conversions in recent versions of Python.

Answer (score 192):

`round` does take negative `ndigits` parameter!

```
>>> round(46,-1)
50
```

may solve your case.

Comment: This doesn't round *up* though. It also returns a `float`, which may or may not be desirable (but I think is worth mentioning).

Comment: true, it rounds to the nearest... on py3, it returns an int though.

Comment: You can easily enough put it inside of int() if you don't want a float. Thanks. This solved my case.

Comment: It's dirty but you could always do

`round(num + 5.1, -1)`

Comment: bests answer right here

Answer (score 26):

Here is one way to do it:

```
>>> n = 46
>>> (n + 9) // 10 * 10
50
```

Comment: Nice trick. Boils down to adding the numbers base minus 1.

Comment: this would fail for numbers like 0.5 or 30.5 and so on (i.e. k*10+a where k is an integer and  0 < a < 1 )

Comment: yes the answer assumes the input in an integer only - not clear from the question that this was a condition, although the example implies this is the case

Answer (score 16):

This will round down correctly as well:

```
>>> n = 46
>>> rem = n % 10
>>> if rem < 5:
...     n = int(n / 10) * 10
... else:
...     n = int((n + 10) / 10) * 10
...
>>> 50
```

Comment: The requirement is specifically to round *up*.

Comment: It helps to have the round down too. Thanks jvasilakes