# How do I round up a number to the nearest 10 in python 3.4.0?

Tags: numbers, rounding

Because "round" will round a number such as 24 **down** to twenty, when I need the answer to be rounded **up** to 30. Please help me! I've been stuck on this for ages :(

Comment: Please show us the function you actually made... will be easier to help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - round up to the nearest ten](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26454649/python-round-up-to-the-nearest-ten)

Comment: Use `x + (-x) % 10`.

Answer (score 0):

Import math

def roundup(x):

```
#rounding method
return int(math.ceil(x / 10.0)) * 10
```

Answer (score 0):

**This function will round both up and down, correctly:**

```py
import math

def roundup(x, n=10):
    res = math.ceil(x/n)*n
    if (x%n < n/2)and (x%n>0):
        res-=n
    return res

num = [5,9,11,15]
r_num = [roundup(n) for n in num]

print(r_num)
# [10, 10, 10, 20]
```

Comment: The OP wants 24 to round *up* to 30.

Comment: This function would also appear to "round" 20 to 10.

Comment: "To the nearest 10" is ambiguous.

Also, corrected code.

Comment: Sure, but the question body is clear enough: the OP is quite explicit about wanting 24 to round to 30.

Comment: AH! Careless of me. _(Should I remove my answer?)_